# SVG embedded into HTML, drag and drop code issues

Tags: javascript, html, svg, draggable

I have an SVG file embedded into an HTML document inside .  I can javascript access the elements in the html and svg using ids and classes.  However, I want to perform some drag and drop on the embedded svg.  I have been using the following example at http://svg-whiz.com/svg/DragAndDrop.svg separating the SVG from the javascript, but it gives me trouble when I embed the SVG in HTML.  The init function in the SVG doesn't work when embedded

```
onload="initSVG(evt)"
```

I need to access the root of the SVG in the HTML so that I can get the drag and drop routines working.  The original code for a standalone svg is written thus:

```
function initSVG(evt)
{
SVGDocument = evt.target.ownerDocument;
SVGRoot = SVGDocument.documentElement;
TrueCoords = SVGRoot.createSVGPoint();
GrabPoint = SVGRoot.createSVGPoint();
}
```

My rewrite is like such, so that it can be run without an onload event call:

```
function initSVG()
{
SVGRoot = document.getElementsByTagName("svg");
TrueCoords = SVGRoot.createSVGPoint();
GrabPoint = SVGRoot.createSVGPoint();
}
```

Which gives the the error: "Object # has no method 'CreateSVGPoint'".  So it doesn't seem to be treating the imported SVG in the same way as a stand alone svg.  How can I get the SVGRoot?

Thanks!

P.S. I know i should probably be using jquery, but I wanted to learn raw DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName` function returns a `NodeList`, not an element.  Try:

```
SVGRoot = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
```